# Unable to use a regex in defroute

Tags: clojure, compojure, ring, luminus

This routes works in Luminus/Compojure/Ring app

```
(GET "/page/:id" [id] (home-page id))
```

but this doesn't and throws an error:

```
(GET ["/page/:id" :id #"^[1-9]\d{0,2}$"] [id] (home-page id))
```

The error is "Page not found", even when I go to the same url "page/2"

Comment: @glts, you're right. why are they redundant, though?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the anchors `^` `$`, which are redundant: apparently the keyword (`:id`) specifies which part of the route string (`":id"`) is to be matched by the regex, in entirety.

The answer to why this is so is likely found in the implementation of this logic, [Clout](https://github.com/weavejester/clout/blob/master/src/clout/core.clj).